# How to best add mvvmcross source into Xamarin Studio on the Mac

Tags: git, debugging, xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm contemplating adding mvvmcross source directly into my project simply so I can set breakpoints and explore things more intimately.  For example, I'm trying to understand why a table view isn't getting updated, even though I think I'm doing everything correctly.  I'd love to set a breakpoint in [MvxTableViewSource.cs](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch/Views/MvxTableViewSource.cs#L56) and see what (if anything) is happening in there.

Anyhow, I see there is a top-level solution file MvvmCross_All.sln -- but I can't just pull that into my own solution.  So then I started poking around for .csproj files, and well -- there are 164 such files.  It seems crazy for me to try to piece together what solution files I should put together.

What is a good approach here?  I feel that stepping through the mvvmcross code would really be educational and help me find problems in my own code as well.

Sidenote:  I was going to add mvvmcross as a git submodule.  Seems like a good fit.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to add Mvvmcross project to your own solution.
Just modify all you reference related to Mvvmcross to Mvvmcross source debug directory.
Then you can debug  and run into Mvvmcross source code.

eg. open properties of Cirrious.MvvmCross and modify path with MvvmCross source path\bin\Debug\Mvx\Droid\Cirrious.MvvmCross.dll
[image]

Hope this can help you.

Comment: what about Xamarin Studio on a Mac?